# Returning only a property of an element passed in to a forEach loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, foreach, callback

```
let bloodGroup = bloodCodeArray.forEach(bloodCode => (bloodCode.code.toUpperCase() === bloodType.toUpperCase()) ? bloodCode.code : bloodType);
```

I expect this to return only a property of 'bloodCode' element (code) in my call back function of an angular code, but this is returning the entire element even though I'm selecting it in the ternary operator. Please explain.

Comment: `forEach` does not return anything, use `map` instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
let bloodGroup = bloodCodeArray
            .filter(bc => (bc.code.toUpperCase() === bloodType.toUpperCase()) ? bc.code : bloodType)
            .map(bg=>bg.code)
            .pop()
```

I was able to resolve this by using this code does anyone has a shorter or prettier way of doing the same?

After going through the comments on the question I realized using forEach will not work as it only returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
let bloodGroup = bloodCodeArray.map(bloodCode => (bloodCode.code.toUpperCase() === bloodType.toUpperCase()) ? bloodCode.code : bloodType);
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for the author, it would be more helpful!

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, You have to use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which returns a new array by applying the callback function on each element of an array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const bloodCodeArray = [{
  code: 'A'
}, {
  code: 'o'
}, {
  code: 'b'
}, {
  code: 'O+'
}];

const bloodType = 'O';

let bloodGroup = bloodCodeArray.map(bloodCode => (bloodCode.code.toUpperCase() === bloodType.toUpperCase()) ? bloodCode.code : bloodType);

console.log(bloodGroup);
```